# Call contract via web3 from KotlinJS

Tags: kotlin, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I want to call the smart contract from KotlinJS using web3.js (v1.x.x).
So, the web3 class contains the class "Eth". The "Eth" class contains the "Contract" class that needs to be initialized.

Please tell me how I can do this on Kotlin **without call js("some code")**.

How can I create external class inside an another external class?

#### Code on JS:

```
var Web3 = require("web3");
var web3 = new Web3("https://rinkeby.infura.io:443");
var json = //some json;
var address = //some address;
var contract = new web.eth.Contract(json, address);
```

Comment: Please add the answer, incase you have resolved it